# WordPress Website slug includes "#/" - Why is it there and how can I remove shebang URL hash?

Tags: wordpress

I've noticed that my WordPress website slug includes the characters `#!/`. For example: `https://bigapplemoving.com/#!/`. I'm unsure why this happened and if it will negatively impact my website's performance.

What's causing this and how can I get it off my website's URLs? Does it come with any risks or downsides?

Its name is shebang URL hash, but I don't know how to remove it.

In page view source, it appears like this:

```html
<a href="https://bigapplemoving.com/" class="custom-logo-link" rel="home" aria-current="page"><img width="106" height="80" src="https://bigapplemoving.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/06/bigapple-moving-and-storage-logo-2.jpg" class="custom-logo" alt="Big Apple Moving &amp; Storage" decoding="async" /></a>                <p class="site-title"><a href="https://bigapplemoving.com/" rel="home">Big Apple Movers NYC</a></p>
                            <p class="site-description">One of The Best NYC Moving Companies</p>
                    </div>
        <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation">
            <button class="menu-toggle" aria-controls="primary-menu" aria-expanded="false">Menu</button>
            <div class="menu-md-new-header-menu-container"><ul id="primary-menu" class="menu"><li id="menu-item-3159" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-3159"><a href="https://bigapplemoving.com/about/">About</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-23931" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-23931"><a href="https://bigapplemoving.com/services/moving/full-service/">Moving</a>
```

Comment: It should be some plugin that appends hash part to your URL's. Most likely for front-end parts. Also anything after `#` is not parsed by back-end

Comment: Thanks @Justinas Is it going to hurt the website?

Comment: On it's own - no